# getting access to web pages on a network switch

Tags: php, network-programming, telnet

I am trying to build a php interface to some hp and cisco switches.  i have some code to connect via telnet and then parse results. But i'm just wondering if anyone know if there is a way to somehow access the web pages that are built into the swtiches. 
lets say for example for an HP 5406 or 3500? 
it would be useful to see their code to see if there's a cleaner way to interpret results from switch commands...
thanks.

Comment: Web interfaces on switches (especially HP and also Netgear, IIRC) tend to be *very* client-side technology heavy. This makes it as near to impossible to extract any useful information from them in PHP as makes no odds. Even if they are just plain HTML, plain text output (via telnet) will almost without fail be considerably easier and less resource hungry to parse than HTML. However, if you examine how these client side apps communicate with the switch, you may find they are talking to an HTTP API that would be easy for you to talk to if you reverse engineer it a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fopen() switches' management interface url. With the help of Live HTTP Headers or some browser plugins similar, you can grab the GET or POST request and parse the response web page, and try to emulate human behavior and try to get some similar result.

If the web interface uses flash or java applet, it'll be harder to implement, depending on its data used to communicate with the switch.

The cleaner way? Hard to implement. Emulating POST and GET request is the most clean way I think.